# tracking uninitialized static variables

Tags: c, valgrind, static-analysis

I need to debug an ugly and huge math C library, probably once produced by f2c. The code is abusing *local* static variables, and unfortunately somewhere it seems to exploit the fact that these are automatically initialized to 0. If its entry function is called with the same input twice, it is giving different results. If I unload the library and reload it again, it works correctly. It needs to be fast, so I would like to get rid of the load/unload.

My question is that how to uncover these errors with valgrind or by any other tool without manually walking through the entire code.

I am hunting places where a local static variable is declared, read first, and written only later. The problem is even further complicated by the fact that the static variables are sometimes passed further via pointers (yep - it is so ugly).

I understand that one can argue that mistakes like this should not be necessary detected by an automatic tool, as in some scenarios this is exactly the intended behaviour. Still, is there a way to make the auto-initialized local static variables "dirty"?

Comment: Interesting question, but valgrind has no knowledge of "local" or "declared".  I think this must be done by code analysis, not executable analysis.

Comment: we use PC Lint, but it generates a hell of a lot of warnings so finding the real hotspots is sometimes like fishing in the dark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The devil is in the details, but this may work for you:

First, get [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). If you are using Unix, your distribution may have a package. The package won't be the last version but it may be good enough and it will save you some time if you install it this way.

Say your example is as below, only so much bigger that it's not obvious what is wrong:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
  static int state;
  int result = x + y + state; // I tested it once and it worked.
  state++;
  return result;
}
```

Type a command like:

```
frama-c -lib-entry -main add -deps ugly.c
```

Options `-lib-entry -main add` mean "look at function `add`". Option `-deps` computes functional dependencies. You'll find these "functional dependencies" in the log:

```
[from] Function add:
     state FROM state; (and default:false)
     \result FROM x; y; state; (and default:false)
```

This lists the **actual** inputs the results of `add` depend on, and the **actual** outputs computed from these inputs, including static variables read from and modified. A static variable that was properly initialized before being used would normally not appear as input, unless the analyzer was unable to determine that it was always initialized before being read from.

The log shows `state` as dependency of `\result`. If you expected the returned result to depend only on the arguments (meaning two calls with the same arguments produce the same result), it's a hint there may be something wrong here, with the variable `state`.

Another hint shown in the above lines is that the function modifies `state`.

This may help or not. Option `-lib-entry` means that the analyzer does not assume that any non-const static variable has kept its value at the time the function under analysis is called, so that may be too imprecise for your code. There are ways around that, but then it is up to you whether you want to gamble the time it takes to learn these ways.

EDIT: here is a more complex example:

```
void initialize_1(int *p)
{
  *p = 0;
}

void initialize_2(int *p)
{
  *p; // I made a mistake here.
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
  static int state1;
  static int state2;

  initialize_1(&state1);
  initialize_2(&state2);

  // This is safe because I have initialized state1 and state2:
  int result = x + y + state1 + state2; 

  state1++;
  state2++;
  return result;
}
```

On this example, the same command produces the results:

```
[from] Function initialize_1:
         state1 FROM p
[from] Function initialize_2:
[from] Function add:
         state1 FROM \nothing
         state2 FROM state2
         \result FROM x; y; state2
```

What you see for `initialize_2` is an empty list of dependencies, meaning the function assigns nothing. I will make this case clearer by displaying an explicit message rather than just an empty list. If you know what any of the functions `initialize_1`, `initialize_2` or `add` is supposed to do, you can compare this a priori knowledge to the results of the analysis and see that something is wrong for `initialize_2` and `add`.

SECOND EDIT: and now my example shows something strange for `initialize_1`, so perhaps I should explain that. Variable `state1` depends on `p` in the sense that `p` is used to write to `state1`, and if `p` had been different, then the final value of `state1` would have been different. Here is a last example:

```
int t[10];

void initialize_index(int i)
{
  t[i] = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  initialize_index(argv[1][0]-'0');
}
```

With the command `frama-c -deps t.c`, the dependencies computed for `initialize_index` are:

```
[from] Function initialize_index:
         t[0..9] FROM i (and SELF)
```

This means that each of the cells depends on `i` (it may be modified if `i` is the index of that particular cell). Each cell may also keep its value (if `i` indicates another cell): this is indicated with the `(and SELF)` mention in the latest version, and was indicated with a more obscure `(and default:true)` in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds useful; I will not try it though, as I have already found my bug with the most primitive method below. BTW, can Frama-C track variables passed through pointers? In my case the statics are sent around, and they may be initialised in a different function.

Comment: @takbal Yes, it can, but in presence of pointers, you may need to describe the memory states in which the functions are called more precisely. I'll edit my answer with a more complete example. In http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-value-analysis.pdf section 2.5.2, this analysis is used to check the dependencies of a complete cryptographic hash function, with pointers and all (but not the most striking example since the code is clean and there's not much to say.

Answer (score 2):

Static code analysis tools are pretty good at finding typical programming errors like the use of uninitialized variables. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C) is a list of free tools that do this for C.

Unfortunately I can't recommend any of the tools in the list. I am only familiar with two commercial products, [Coverity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity) and [Klocwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klocwork). Coverity is very good (and expensive). Klocwork is so so (but less expensive).

Comment: Why don't you just initialize all local variables to zero when they are declared? Is this a big code base?

Comment: Yes it is huge. You are right, I could surely do some regexp trick to turn all definitions into 0-based init, or even NaN for doubles. This is a path I have not tried in the end.

Answer (score 2):

What I did in the end is removed all static qualifiers from the code by '#define static'. This turns uninitialised static usage into invalid use, and the type of abuse I am hunting can be uncovered by the tools.

In my actual case this was enough to determine the place of the bug, but in a more general situation it should be refined if static's are actually doing something important, by gradually re-adding 'static' when the code fails to continue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any library that does this for you, but I would look into using regular expressions to find them. Something like

rgrep "static\s*int" path/to/src/root | grep -v = | grep -v "("

That should return all static int variables declared without an equals sign, and the last pipe should remove anything with parenthesis in them (getting rid of funcions). There's a good change that this won't work exactly for you, but playing around with grep may be the fastest way for you to track this down.

Of course, once you find one that works you can replace int with all of the other kinds of variables to search for those too. HTH

Comment: A shame but practically all variables are declared static without init... it is probably the wrongdoing of f2c.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that how to uncover these errors ...

But these *aren't* errors: the expectation that a static variable is initialized to 0 is perfectly valid, as is assigning some other value to it.

So asking for a tool that will automatically find *non*-errors is unlikely to produce a satisfying result.

From your description, it appears that `somefunc()` returns correct result first time it is called, and incorrect result on subsequent calls.

The simplest way to debug such problems is to have two GDB sessions side-by-side: one freshly-loaded (will compute correct answer), and one with "second iteration" (will compute wrong answer). Then step through both sessions "in parallel", and see where their computation or control flow starts to diverge.

Since you can usually effectively divide the problem in half, it often doesn't take long to find the bug. Bugs that *always* reproduce are the easiest ones to find. Just do it.

Comment: As I said in the original post, I understand that from the viewpoint of the compiler/linker it is not a bug. The question is more like how to turn this kind of usage into a bug which can be detected automatically.