# Is there a static C analyzer which detects uninitialized static variables?

Tags: c, static, initialization, static-analysis

We have hit a problem with some C code in embedded firmware which only occurred on 1 in 200 systems, and boiled down to use of a global static variable before it had been initialized.

In normal C, this wouldn't be a problem because static variables get initialized to 0, but this embedded system is so space/time-constrained that there is no cinit, so static variables do not get zeroed.

Now that we have spotted the problem, we have been able to fix it, but we want to spot it in future 100% - 1 in 200 systems was painful to hunt down, and next time it might be 1 in 5000, 1 in a million or less, so no amount of testing can give us complete confidence.

We use cppcheck and SonarQube for static analysis, but we haven't found how to catch this error with those.

1. Is there an option in either cppcheck or SonarQube which would detect use of static global variables before initialization?  If so, how do we use it?
2. If not, is there any other static analysis tool which does provide this warning?

Comment: I believe not zeroing out static variables is "fooling" your compiler (and the programmer), that is assuming they are zero. So if you explicitly setting some variable like this to zero elsewhere, it might just optimize away this operation as it thinks it is zero anyway.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7822740/281460

Comment: @jwir3 I looked at that, but that was talking about local static variables within functions, rather than global static variables.

Comment: @eugene sh. That's exactly the problem. If we know we have it, we can handle it, but we want a tool which could tell us we potentially have the problem case for any changes in future.

Comment: @IanBrockbank It won't help. The tool will analyze the source code, which might have the initialization. But the compiler will optimize this initialization out. Better find the resources to properly initialize the `.data` and `.bss`. Or don't use static variables if you can't.